# What is null safe way to convert array to string using Thymeleaf

Tags: arrays, thymeleaf, tostring

I'm trying to convert String array to String using Thymeleaf.

```
th:value="${#strings.arrayJoin(result.param.searchCondition.mstoneIds, ',')}"
```

The problem, that if my array is null I get an exception. Are there any null safe ways to convert Array to String?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a conditional check like this

```
th:value="${result.param.searchCondition.mstoneIds != null} ? ${#strings.arrayJoin(result.param.searchCondition.mstoneIds, ',')} : 'null value'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
But are there any way to do it null safe without checking?
Like Arrays.toString() in java ?

Comment: You could set the mstoneIds be a empty array instead of null value. That way you never need to worry about null values.